# TFS git commit change work item status

Tags: git, tfs

I know that you can link workitem with `#1234` commit message syntax.

Is there a way to change work item status that way. Say, resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not currently a way to do this. I would however expect to see these kind of things comming down the line as MS has committed to feature parity, where possible with TFVC.

Comment: We currently face this issue as well. Is there any post talking about this feature ?

Answer (score 1):

Finally it works!

Using the keyword `fix`, `fixes` or `fixed #ID` will close the workitem but you need to activate this feature.

Detailed instructions: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/devops/repos/git/resolution-mentions?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 0):

As [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/add-links-to-work-items?view=azure-devops) article says, we can use `#ID` to link to work items.
[image]