# Close a work item via the commit message

Tags: git, azure-devops

Is there a way to close a work item using the commit message using VSTS? I tried:  Fixes #123, Closes #123, or Resolves #123 but that only associates the commit to the work item.

So basically I am looking at closing issues via commit messages like in github: https://help.github.com/articles/closing-issues-via-commit-messages/
But using vs team services.

Comment: been I while since question asked... Have you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there isn't any way to do this for now.

Similar question: [TFS git commit change work item status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25267191/tfs-git-commit-change-work-item-status)

Feature request on VSTS User Voice: [Update work items on commit for git](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/6380299-update-work-items-on-commit-for-git)

Answer (score 7):

Finally in 2019 they implemented this as a a light version of gitlab.

Using the keyword `fix`, `fixes` or `fixed #ID` will close the Workitem.

Detailed instructions: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/devops/repos/git/resolution-mentions?view=azure-devops

Comment: Took a few years but real glad they got to it. Tanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

I followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/add-links-to-work-items?view=azure-devops) article and able to link work items using `#ID`. You can use the `#ID` control in pull request discussions, commit comments, changeset comments, and shelveset comments.

[image]